# Subscript in molecule over reaction arrow

Tags: equations, subscripts, chemistry, chemformula

I am writing a report that requires chemical reactions to be numbered and have used the following code to do so:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eq:formloss1}
\ch{HCHO + ^.OH -> CHO^. + H2O} \\
\ch{HCHO + \textit{hv_{uv}} ->[O2] CHO^. + HO2} \\
\label{eq:formloss2}
\ch{HCHO + \textit{hv_{uv}} -> CO + H2}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

But in the second equation the O2 (which is above the reaction arrow) doesn't subscript the 2, which I need it to do. How can I force it to subscript this? And if it requires changing the packages I'm using, how to I keep the equations numbered?

Comment: According to the manual you should use ->[ O2 ]  (note the extra spaces) if you want the 2 subscripted.

Answer (score 3):

From `chemformula`'s manual:

> `chemformula` distinguishes between different types of input. These
>   different parts *have* to be separated with blanks:
>
> ```
> \ch{part1 part2 part3 part4}
> ```

The same holds for formulas above or below arrows. This means you have to write

```
->[ O2 ]
```

`chemformula` needs formulas enclosed with spaces to correctly detect wether an input is a formula/a stoichiometric factor/an arrow…

Secondly I'd write `$h\nu_{\textup{uv}}$` instead of `\textit{hv_{uv}}`. By using math mode you'll get the right spacing between the Planck constant and the frequency. Also I'm quite sure you want the frequency `\nu` and not `v` (velocity?). The subscript seems to be a label, so it should be upright again.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{gather}
    \ch{HCHO + ^.OH -> CHO^. + H2O} \label{eq:formloss1} \\
    \ch{HCHO + $h\nu_{\textup{uv}}$ ->[ O2 ] CHO^. + HO2} \\
    \ch{HCHO + $h\nu_{\textup{uv}}$ -> CO + H2} \label{eq:formloss2}
  \end{gather}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way: do you really *need* `eqnarray`? I suggest you read [Avoid `eqnarray`](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf) by Lars Madsen and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I used `mhchem` package, which solves your problem. Here is the code. You should also install `chemgreek` as `mhchem` uses it.
(Note that the command for chemical equation is `\ce`.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eq:formloss1}
\ce{HCHO + ^.OH -> CHO^. + H2O} \\
\ce{HCHO + $hv_{uv}$ ->[O2] CHO^. + HO2} \\
\label{eq:formloss2}
\ce{HCHO + $hv_{uv}$ -> CO + H2}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't suggest people to install `chemgreek` manually! I've had quite a few “bug reports” because people did that instead of updating their distribution and having `chemgreek` installed and ready to use…